# PHP count rows for date range for previous month only and not from last 30 days to current date

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like the database to count how many reports were generated for last month only and not from the current date backwards a month as it currently is e.g. 16/08/15 to 16/08/15. For example, I would like it to only count the total for August 2015, then once it is October, count the data for September 2015, so you can look back at the previous month how many reports were generated in the database.

I hope that makes sense? It will be used to count how many reports an employee has created to work out commission.

```
<?php
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT count(inventory_id) cc FROM inventories WHERE inventory_date > CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH")) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            printf("<div class='col-6 statsMonth inventoryMonthStats'>Inventories in 30 days <span class='statCircle'>%d</span></div>", $row['cc']);
        $result->close();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gets a bit ugly, but... assuming you always want "previous" month:

```
SELECT ...
...
WHERE YEAR(inventory_date) = YEAR(now() - interval 1 month)
  AND MONTH(inventory_date) = MONTH(now() - interval 1 month)
```

If you want arbitrary previous months, then swap `now()` for a date in the month you want to calculate the "previous" of.